# Comparing/trending test data with googletest and Jenkins

Tags: performance, junit, jenkins, googletest

My C++ project uses [googletest](https://github.com/google/googletest) to produce XML results in the JUnit format for [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/). This is working well for pass/fail results and test durations.

Some of my tests measure code performance and assert that this exceeds some threshold. I would like to extend this to charting the performance data over successive builds. I use the googletest `RecordProperty` method to [log additional information](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/advanced.md#logging-additional-information) in the XML:

```
<testcase name="MyTest" status="run" time="3.964" classname="MyTestSuite" PerformanceData="131" />
```

**How can I configure Jenkins or one of its plugins to chart `PerformanceData` (or an equivalent record) across successive builds?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the [Plot Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plot+Plugin) to plot the performance numbers.

Comment: Thanks - I originally mistook your suggestion for the [Measurement Plots plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Measurement+Plots+Plugin) that I had already tried without success. This one looks better.